# iPhone 6.1 simulator screen resolution is 320x548 instead of 640x1136, why does it heppend?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova, resolution

I create an application for iPhone using PhoneGAP. I create design of application for 640x1136 resolution. But when I tried to run application into iPhone 6.1 simulator the resolution was 320x548 instead of 640x1136. I check the simulation screen resolution using following JavaScript code.

$("#width").text(window.innerWidth);
$("#height").text(window.innerHeight);

To accomplish this, I tried the following steps

1. Edit your Info.plist file in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/Devices/iPhone (Retina).deviceinfo/
2. Open the .plist file in XCode and add the following key/value pairs,

eagle : 640
giraffe:1136

1. Save the file and restart your simulator.
2. Select iPhone (Retina) to see the new resolution.

But it doesn't help.

Could you please help me.

Thanks in advance
Sorry for my bad english

Comment: There's a property called Scale somewhere. I think it's 2.0 for an iPhone 5.

Comment: @ta.speot.is It's `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];`

Comment: Expected behavior. The resolution is in _points_, not _pixels_. Your code should use points so it will run on any device--retina or non-retina. (To clarify--on a retina display, each screen pixel is 0.5x0.5 points, on non retina, the pixels are twice that size, 1x1 points)

Comment: @ta.speot.is where can I find that property?
I find scale property in '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/Resources/Devices/iPhone (Retina).deviceinfo/Info.plist'
it was 2, I change it to 1, but it not help. Screen resolution stayed the same․

Comment: @0x7fffffff I create an application using PhoneGap technology. Where and What exactly should I do with [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

Comment: @nielsbot But How I know the 
$("#width").text(window.innerWidth);
function gets resolution in pixels. Am I correct?

Comment: You get resolution in points always. I don't understand your question... What's wrong with using points?

Comment: Is it mean that I should change design from pixel to point?

Answer (score 1):

When you run on the simulator you still need to select the "hardware" that you are running on.  When running the simulator choose Hardware -> Device and select the correct device (with Retina or not) to test with.

Comment: In simulator I tried to select Device as iPhone, iPhone (Retina 3.5-inch), iPhone (Retina 4-inch). Below please find results:
iPhone: 320x460
iPhone (Retina 3.5-inch): 320x548
iPhone (Retina 4-inch): 320x548